# Pandas groupby fillna with first valid value (window functions)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where I need to fillnas conditionally, with the first value from the appropriate groupby, but I can't figure it out.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_dict = {
    'id':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'data':['A', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'B', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'C', np.nan, np.nan]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

I need to create a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
final_dict = {
    'id':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'data':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
}
final = pd.DataFrame(final_dict)
```

My instince is to groupby `id` and then do a `.fillna(something)` but I can't figure out what to do.

I've tried

```
df.groupby('id')['data'].fillna(df['data'].first_valid_index())
```

but that puts `0`s instead of copying what I want.

I also have another partial solution:

```
for col_name, data in df.items():
    df[col_name] = df.groupby('id').apply(
        lambda x: x[col_name].fillna(x.loc[x[col_name].last_valid_index(), col_name])
    ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### `fillna`, `transform`, `first`

```
df.fillna({'data': df.groupby('id')['data'].transform('first')})

  data  id
0    A   1
1    A   1
2    A   1
3    A   1
4    B   2
5    B   2
6    B   2
7    B   2
```

---

1. `transform` to get something per group then broadcast across group
2. `'first'` grabs the first valid value per group
3. `fillna` takes a dictionary where you can specify which column to fill with what

Comment: Thanks! Will this work with the last 3 of `id=2` where `data='C'`?

Comment: it will keep the `'C'` but fill in missing with `'B'`.

Answer (score 2):

pandas' `fillna` has a method which does this for us:

```
df.groupby('id')['data'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This assumes that there are no null values to fill prior to the first non-null value in that group.  If there were, it would leave them null.  That may be what you want but you should be clear on the difference.  Also, if there are multiple gaps, this fills in with the most recent non-null value instead of the first non-null of the group.  Again, that may be what you want but you should know the difference.

Comment: The first assumption is true by design for my data, and the second is what I want too.

Comment: That's great then.  Also, your question needs some cleaning up.  Your input dataframe has no hint of a `'C'`.  You probably want to provide a valid input to achieve the output desired.  Also, you wanting to forward fill was not obvious, hence my confusion.  You could improve the quality by making that clearer as well.  However, in doing so you likely make this a duplicate question... but that's ok too.  I'll leave it up to you if you want me to delete my post.  It doesn't at all answer your question.